# What does "libel act" mean?

Tags: meaning, definition

What does "LIBEL ACT" mean? Does "the state of things was even more in evidence means that the situation was worse than England or not?

> Even at the present day the air is charged with prejudice. If any man of standing at the present instant were to enter a London newspaper office and say that he had detected a medium in fraud, the matter would be seized upon eagerly and broadcast over the country; while if the same man proclaimed that he had beyond all question satisfied himself that the phenomena were true, it is doubtful if he would get a paragraph. The scale is always heavily weighted. In America, where there is practically no **Libel Act**, and where the Press is often violent and sensational, **this state of things was—and possibly is—even more in evidence**.

*[The History of Spiritualism](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html#chap12)*   By A.C Doyle
<sub>XII: THE EDDY BROTHERS AND THE HOLMESES</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libel is the publication of false statement that is damaging to a person's reputation; a written defamation.  [The Libel Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libel_Act_1843) is the actual legislation enacted that outlines the legal positions.  So, in the USA, where that was no Libel legislation, the press were free to publish negative articles and refute to a much greater extent without fear of prosecution.

Comment: In Britain, laws are created by 'Acts of Parliament', and are informally referred to by a name, and often the year the legislation was passed by Parliament, eg the Theft Act 1985.

Comment: There were and are libel laws in the USA.  However, they make winning a case much more difficult because of the first amendment.